# How do I remove the unnecessary part of this file?

Tags: command-line, bash, text-processing

I have this .scp files which contains the the full command needed to for converting a bunch of files.

This files was generated by a different script, for a different purpose but now I need it convert a bunch of files.

Problem is though that each file start with the filename of the files being converted, which would not work when i want to execute it..

How do I remove the first of the file, such that I can convert all the files, just as easy as executing a script?

Here is a sample of how the text in file is formatted.

```
fcaw-b-an406 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an406-fcaw-b.sph |
fcaw-b-an407 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an407-fcaw-b.sph |
fcaw-b-an408 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an408-fcaw-b.sph |
fcaw-b-an409 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an409-fcaw-b.sph |
fcaw-b-an410 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an410-fcaw-b.sph |
fcaw-b-cen1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/cen1-fcaw-b.sph |...
```

**Desired output**

```
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an406-fcaw-b.sph |
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an407-fcaw-b.sph |
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an408-fcaw-b.sph |
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an409-fcaw-b.sph |
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/an410-fcaw-b.sph |
/home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/../../../../tools/sph2pipe_v2.5/sph2pipe -f wav -p -c 1 /home/k/kaldi-trunk/egs/start/s5/data/train/fcaw/cen1-fcaw-b.sph |...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Many ways:

---

- `grep` with PCRE (`-P`):

  ```
  grep -Po '^[^\s]+\s+\K.*' file.txt
  ```

  - `^[^\s]+\s+` matches the first field along with trailing whitespace, `\K` discards the match, and then `.*` matches the rest of the line and gets printed

---

- `sed`:

  ```
  sed -E 's/^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+//' file.txt
  ```

  - `^[^[:blank:]]+[[:blank:]]+` matches the first field, again with the trailing whitespace(s) and is replaced with empty string

---

- `awk`:

  ```
  awk -F "[[:blank:]]+" '{$1=""; print substr($0, 2)}' file.txt
  ```

  - `-F "[[:blank:]]+"` sets field separator as one or more whitespaces, `$1=""` sets first field as empty string, this introduces a whitespace in front, so we need to do string slicing with substr($0, 2)` to get characters starting from second

---

- `cut`:

  ```
  cut -d" " -f2- file.txt
  ```

  - `-d" "` sets the delimiter as space, and `-f2-` prints the fields starting from second

---

- `bash`:

  ```
  while read -r _ desired; do echo "$desired"; done <file.txt
  ```

  - Reading each line and sets the first field as giveaway variable `_`, `desired` contains the remaining portion, and gets printed by `echo "$desired"`

---

- `perl`:

  ```
  perl -pe 's/^[^\s]+\s+//' file.txt
  ```

  - Similar logic to the `sed` one

---

- `python`:

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  with open('file.txt') as f:
      for line in f:
          print line.split(' ', 1)[1]
  ```

  - Reading each line, and `line.split(' ', 1)` will `split` on space with a maximum of `1` splitting operation, so the index 0 will contain first word, and index 1 will have the desired portion (i.e. from second word till end)

Comment: `cut` only did it for the first line...

Comment: Sorry.. But it doesn't seem to work..

Comment: @BobBurt It should do for all lines, working fine for me on GNU `coreutils 8.21`. Which version of `coreutils` you have?

Comment: @BobBurt All codes are tested and working perfectly on your example.

Comment: (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Comment: here is the full file http://pastebin.com/nNLnhWFG

Your code doesn't change anything.. I tested the bash, python and cut command

Comment: file.txt is intended to be the input file and not the output file right?

Comment: @BobBurt Yes, i got where you are getting confused. We are not changing input file in place. Although many of these commands can modify the input in place, but if you want to save the output in another file, use output redirection e.g. `awk ....input.txt >output.txt`

Comment: Ahh.. Sorry  I though your code created an output file, or edited the original file, didn't notice the output on the terminal... >> output.txt and it worked..

Comment: @BobBurt Note that `>>` will append the file while `>` will overwrite any content. Make your choice.

Comment: yes.. That was intended.. I have two files..

Comment: A little suggestion for your Python snippet: instead of splitting the whole line and joining all but the first part together again, just use `line.split(" ", 1)[1]` or `line.partition(" ")[2]` to avoid unnecessary string splitting and re-joining.

Comment: @ByteCommander Thanks, edited. I need to revisit these :/